# How do you change multiple element's background-position X value but keep their Y value the same?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, background-position

I have 5 elements that each share the same background-image icon sprite. Their background position is set differently to target their icon on the icon sprite.

for example:

```
.icons{background-image: url('img/sprite.svg');}

.icon1{background-position: 10px 10px;}
.icon2{background-position: 10px 20px;}
.icon3{background-position: 10px 30px;}
.icon4{background-position: 10px 40px;}
.icon5{background-position: 10px 50px;}
```

My goal is to change the X value of the background-position of every icon in a media query but I don't know how to change the X value of every icon WITHOUT having to change the Y value AND having to hardcode every background-position manually into the media query for each .icon element.

Comment: You can use `background-position-x` in all browsers except Opera and FF; http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y

Comment: @powerbuoy That should be an answer :)

Comment: if you want to change it dynamically you can use `position()` method in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not an official property, IE, Chrome and Safari all support `background-position-x` (and `y`) so if you can live with no FF (or Opera) support you can use that.

You can read more about it here: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y